# RewriteRule issues with one variable

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to convert url `example.com/index/about` to `example.com/index.php?id=about`
That's text of my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule index\/^([A-Za-z]+)$ index.php?id=$1
```

It should do it as I understand. But when I go to example.com/index/about it says that it's not found on server. Suggestions?

Comment: added some rewrite cond this too doesn't works.

Comment: Remove the lines with `RewriteCond`. <-- Ignore that, change the regex to `^index\/([A-Za-z]+)$` and it works. Test here: http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/

Comment: Starnge this works on htacces.madewithlove.be but on server this is internal server error. However mod_rewrite is on.

Comment: Then you have another error somewhere. It's working fine on my xampp machine.

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine On
Options -MultiViews
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^index\/([A-Za-z]*)$ index.php?id=$1
```

This removed server error.